# Basic авторизация с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript

Имеем: страницу *djd.service.com* на которой установлена базовая авторизация (страница открывается только при подаче заголовка `Authorization:Basic {base64(username:password)}`)
страницу *fhd.admin.ru*, зайдя на которую, пользователь должен автоматически авторизоваться на странице *djd.service.com* (т.е. чтобы при заходе на неё браузер автоматически передавал заголовок `Authorization:Basic {base64(username:password)}`, как происходит тогда, когда пользователь вручную вводит username и password в соответствующее окно (генерируемое самим браузером).

Подскажите, реализуемо ли это вообще?

Comment: Ну просто отправьте заголовок Authorization в запросе, что у вас не получается?

Comment: @Inventor первый вопрос, браузер его запомнит?

Comment: @Inventor второй вопрос, я попробовал сделать, пишет _No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource._ попробовал в htaccess вписать разрешение, но оно отображается только при уже авторизованном пользователе

Comment: Чтобы браузер запомнил используйте `localStorage` и доставайте оттуда значение при каждом запросе, ошибка `CORS` возникает из-за того, что вы делаете кроссдоменный запрос, ваш сервер должен сказать браузеру, что поддерживает такое соединение (посмотрите что такое `CORS`)

Comment: @Inventor я почитал, советы что есть в интернете (правка htaccess) не помогли, они подействовали только на уже открытую страницу

Comment: Причём тут `htaccess`? Посмотрите что такое `CORS`, apache тут не при чём, это логика работы вашего сервера

Comment: @Inventor Как вы можете видеть, заголовок Origin содержит именно источник (домен/протокол/порт), без пути.
Сервер может проверить Origin и, если он согласен принять такой запрос, добавить особый заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin к ответу. Этот заголовок должен содержать разрешённый источник (в нашем случае https://javascript.info) или звёздочку *. Тогда ответ успешен, в противном случае возникает ошибка.
Так же прочитал что особый заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin задаётся в htaccess для apache, если знаете как задать его иначе - объясните, плиз

Comment: Идёте в то место, где у вас обрабатывается запрос и добавляете заголовок к ответу, кроме того CORS требует, чтобы ваш сервер обрабатывал OPTIONS запросы